# How to pull images from private docker registry in drone ci pipeline

Tags: docker, drone.io

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55433518/4540647)

## Problem

- I need to use an image from a private docker image registry in my test pipeline
- I could not find any (edit: overlooked) up to date documentation on how to use a private docker registry with drone in general or with specifically configured repositories.

## Situation

os version: ubuntu 18.04 lts
drone version: 1.0.0
docker version: 18.09.4
docker-compose version: 1.23.2

I host drone ci myself with docker and docker-compose (one master, two agents).

An example pipeline config:

```
---

kind: pipeline
name: integration

steps:
  - name: tests
    image: private-registry.example.com/nodejs/special
    commands:
      - npm i
      - npm run test
    when:
      event:
        - push
        - pull_request
...
```

### drone docs

The documentation of drone refers to configuring a private registry without providing a link or giving further details on how to accomplish this on [the documentation page about pipeline steps](https://docs.drone.io/user-guide/pipeline/steps/#image) in the image section stating:

> If the image does not exist, Drone instructs Docker to pull it. If the image is private you will need to configure registry credentials.

---

I found this question where the op refers to [this page](http://docs.drone.io/manage-registry-credentials/#configuration) in the docs that does not exist anymore.

Both, the author of the question and the author of the accepted answer are using the drone cli to add a registry to drone with the `registry` command. But unfortunately this command is not available anymore.

The current drone cli usage message looks like the following:

```
NAME:
   drone - command line utility

USAGE:
   drone [global options] command [command options] [arguments...]

VERSION:
   1.0.7

COMMANDS:
     build      manage builds
     cron       manage cron jobs
     log        manage logs
     encrypt    encrypt a secret
     exec       execute a local build
     info       show information about the current user
     repo       manage repositories
     user       manage users
     secret     manage secrets
     server     manage servers
     queue      queue operations
     autoscale  manage autoscaling
     fmt        format the yaml file
     convert    convert legacy format
     lint       lint the yaml file
     sign       sign the yaml file
     jsonnet    generate .drone.yml from jsonnet
     script     generate .drone.yml from script
     plugins    plugin helper functions
     help, h    Shows a list of commands or help for one command

GLOBAL OPTIONS:
   -t value, --token value   server auth token [$DRONE_TOKEN]
   -s value, --server value  server address [$DRONE_SERVER]
   --autoscaler value        autoscaler address [$DRONE_AUTOSCALER]
   --help, -h                show help
   --version, -v             print the version
```

---

I found a [github issue](https://github.com/drone/drone/pull/615) referring to a [pull request](https://github.com/drone/drone/pull/617) adding a docker section from 2014. That all seems to have been moved to the [docker](https://docs.drone.io/examples/service/docker/) and [docker:dind](https://docs.drone.io/examples/service/docker_dind/) plugins respectively.

## Questions

1. So finally, is there a way to add a private docker registry to drone and how can one do it?
2. Is there documentation providing details on how to do it?

Comment: but what about the implicit steps like (clone) which uses `drone/git` image .. i want to use `nexus.company.local/drone/git` instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution

There is indeed a [documentation section](https://docs.drone.io/pipeline/docker/syntax/images/#pulling-private-images) specifically for private docker image registries.

> ## Image Pull Secrets
>
> In order to download a private image you will need to provide a docker
> registry config file, which embeds the authentication credentials to
> the registry.
>
> Example .docker/config.json file:
>
> ```json
> {
>   "auths": {
>     "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
>       "auth": "b2N0b2NhdDpjb3JyZWN0LWhvcnNlLWJhdHRlcnktc3RhcGxl"
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> The contents of the file should be stored as a secret, where the named
> secret is referenced in the image_pull_secrets section of the yaml.
>
> ```yaml
> kind: pipeline
> name: default
> type: docker
>
> steps:
> - name: build   
>   image: testing/test-image   
>   commands:
>   - go build
>   - go test
>
> image_pull_secrets:
> - dockerconfigjson
> ```

So what one has to do is to perform a `docker login <registry host>` and put the generated credentials from `~/.docker/config.json` in a secret, in the example called `dockerconfigjson`.

Comment: Updated link to the doc : 
https://docker-runner.docs.drone.io/configuration/images/

Comment: Next doc link update: https://docs.drone.io/pipeline/docker/syntax/images/#pulling-private-images

Comment: Emm! but what about the implicit steps like (clone) which uses `drone/git` image .. i want to use `nexus.company.local/drone/git` instead

Comment: If you find that `.auths.<address>` is empty in `~/.docker/config.json`, and that there is a `.credsStore: ...` entry in the file, then this means that an executable named `docker-credentials-<value-of-credsStore` has responsibility for storing the credentials - use it to retrieve them. (see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full workflow AWS ECR.
It is assumed that

- you have a working `aws` CLI installation
- you have a working `drone` CLI installation

1. Get a token for your registry: `aws ecr get-login-password --region <your region>`
2. Add the token to the organization in Drone CI: `drone orgsecret add <organization> my-pull-secret <secret from step 1>`
3. Add the following to your `.drone.yml`:

   ```yaml
   image_pull_secrets:
     - my-pull-secret
   ```

For Google Cloud the secret cannot be a token but instead a JSON file as [described in the GCloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json-key).