# Drone CI can't authenticate with private repository

Tags: docker, harbor, drone.io

The following `.drone.yml`:

```
kind: pipeline

steps:
- name: publish
  image: registry.example.com/hub/plugins/docker
  settings:
    registry: registry.example.com
    repo: registry.example.com/some/repo
    tags: latest
    username:
      from_secret: registry-user
    password:
      from_secret: registry-pass

image_pull_secrets:
  - docker-token
```

fails with the following error:

> publish: Error response from daemon: unauthorized: unauthorized to access repository: hub/plugins/docker, action: pull: unauthorized to access repository: hub/plugins/docker, action: pull

where `registry.thechubbypanda.net/hub` is a proxy for `hub.docker.com`.

The secret `docker-token` was created with cli command: `drone secret add --name docker-token --data ~/.docker/config.json --repository some/repo`.

The `~/.docker/config.json` file's contents is:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://registry.example.com": {
            "auth": "MYLEGITTOKEN"
        }
    }
}
```

I believe that I've followed the steps on the [drone docs](https://docs.drone.io/pipeline/docker/syntax/images/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55431628/how-to-pull-images-from-private-docker-registry-in-drone-ci-pipeline) correctly.